# it is possible to work with image in Ignite?

Tags: c#, ignite

Sorry, i starting to work with Apache Ignite and my question is, it is possible to work with images (stream) in Ignite cache, i mean if would that be a best practice?

I hope you can help me solve this doubt.

Comment: What is "bitmap"? Is it a tool? A data type?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I mean a data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question might be too broad or potentially too opinion-based for SO, there are some general pointers to give.

You can certainly store images as byte arrays in Ignite. Ignite won't know these are images - for the storage, it's just some binary data.

Ignite is best equipped for small-to-medium-sized records. There isn't a particular size limit but some tuning may be required when there the object size is roughly >1MB.

There aren't any special features for image processing. However, the power of Ignite is that you can deploy and run fully-featured code on the server using Compute Grid. You can deploy a 3rd party library that deals with images, and call it from a compute jobs that reads the image data from the cache without sending it over the network.

Comment: Thank you. Stanislav. 

My intention is save to cache the images with Ignite. In the first request, if the image not exist in cache, it is read from the disk and an resize the original image and the result is saved in the cache, for a next read the image will already exist in the cache.

Comment: This will work assuming the images are not large (sounds like they aren't), just use key-value API to store the images as a byte array. You can also go extra-clever and create a custom CacheStore with read-through enabled that will handle the caching instead of doing that on the application. Depending on how you deploy, you may see extra performance boost from that by saving on traffic. Plus you'll get style points and that's what matters most ;)

Comment: Thank's Stanislav.